# PHP preg_replace usage versus a brute force approach

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to determine if it is possible to do the following using preg_replace and if so can you show me an example with comments so I learn from it.

I have some html code that looks something like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item"><a href="/clients-login-english/">Login**</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item"><a href="/clients-create-account-english/">Create Account%%</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is find the position of a "code", in this case the "* *" or the "%%" and remove the text that starts at the preceeding < li and ends with the next < /li >. So if I use the preg_replace on this and am looking for the "**" it would end up looking like:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">

<li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item"><a href="/clients-create-account-english/">Create Account%%</a></li>
</ul>
```

My original thought is to use a brute force approach and use stripos to find the "**" and then loop backwards from there to find the < li and then look for the < /li > after it and rebuild the string minus this section but it seems there has to be an easier way.

Comment: In your example, when you find `**` on `Login**`, you remove the `<a>` and its parent `<li>` When do you stop removing nodes?

Comment: Can you show your `preg_replace` usage?

Comment: I want to keep removing till no more < li ** < /li > lines exist in the string.

Comment: Can `**` also appear in other places i.e. outside `<a>` and `</a>`?

Comment: The string I am searching in will always look like the example I gave so no it will not appear outside of the < a > < /a >.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that parsing HTML using regex is error prone. Please avoid it unless until you're very sure of the HTML text you're getting.

Having said that here is a regex based code to do what you want:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item"><a href="/clients-login-english/">Login**</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item"><a href="/clients-create-account-english/">Create Account%%</a></li>
</ul>
EOF;
echo preg_replace('#<li\s.*?<a[^\*]+\*\*</a></li>#s', '', $html). "\n";
```

#### EDIT: Here is the DOM based (and RECOMMENDED) way to achieve above:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nlist = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='sub-menu']/li");

$nodesToDelete = array();
$numnodes = $nlist->length;
for($i=0; $i < $numnodes; $i++) {
   $node = $nlist->item($i);
   $val = $node->nodeValue;
   if (strstr($val, '**'))
      $nodesToDelete[] = $node;
}

foreach($nodesToDelete as $node)
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

$newHTML =  $doc->saveHTML();
echo $newHTML;
```

Comment: Be careful deleting nodes from a DOMNodeList as you iterate over it. One solution is to store references to the nodes to delete and delete them afterwards, or another way is to simply iterate backwards. Also, `$nlist->length` is apparently calculated each time so it may be better done outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestions, edited the answer accordingly.